# http handler for .asmx file is throwing 401 error

Tags: c#, .net, redirect, iis-7.5, httphandler

I have made a custom httphandler to redirect old .asmx request to different server.

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        int i = 0;

        string methodName = context.Request.PathInfo.Trim('/');

        string baseUrl = "http://www.example.com/xy.asmx";

        string newURL = baseUrl + "/" + methodName;

        context.Response.Redirect(newURL, false);



    }
```

This should be pretty trivial task but I am getting unauthorized exception for no reason.
      {"Message":"Authentication         failed.","StackTrace":null,"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}

I have even disable the authentication.

Can some one tell me whats going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like It was a post request and post request are not allowed to be redirected. Hence the error.

Why error is happening I am not sure. But I will leave it as is for now.

-